Media Session on Geckoview Android
I'm trying to implement the media session API on an app with geckoview.
I followed another  Stackoverflow post, where it says to insert a delegate. This is my code:
GeckoView view = findViewById(R.id.geckoview);
    GeckoSession session = new GeckoSession();
    GeckoRuntime runtime = GeckoRuntime.create(this);
    session.open(runtime);
    view.setSession(session);
    MyMediaSessionDelegate myDelegate = new MyMediaSessionDelegate();
    session.setMediaSessionDelegate(myDelegate);
    session.loadUri("https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media-session/audio.html");

This is my delegate :
public class MyMediaSessionDelegate implements MediaSession.Delegate {

@Override
public void onActivated(GeckoSession session, MediaSession mediaSession) {
    Log.d("dev", "onActivated fired");

} ....

but I don't get any logs when I start the application. As if the delegate didn't work.
Notification enabled.
